# Change Elements HTML but Ignore Last Child

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the way I have my HTML marked up....

```
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="body">

  <div class="content">don't change this</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to change the html inside of `.body` without changing the html inside of `.content`?

**EDIT**:

I'm working on my code editor and my `<script>` tag in this case is replaced with `.content`, and `<body>` tag is replaced with `.body`.

The [`.before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) API seems to be the best solution for my case except if only 3 characters are added (ex. lol). The result in `.body` is (ex. lolollol)

```js
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  $('.content').before(this.value)
  return false
}).trigger('keyup')
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 98%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="body">
  
  <div class="content">don't change this</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends on what the change is. Is it style, events, etc.?

Comment: I'm working on my code editor and my <script> tag in this case is replaced with `.content`, and `<body>` tag is replaced with `.body`.

Comment: Why don't you have another tag which will wrap everything inside body except content?

Comment: and it will not get deleted if you use `.before` by using backspace already deleted my answer thanks to AI.G.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tricky, because `.body` may contain text nodes.

jQuery's [**`contents()`**](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) method helps :

```js
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  $('.body')
    .contents()                             //get both text nodes and element nodes
    .each(function() {
      if(this.className !== 'content') {
        this.nodeValue= this.innerHTML= ''; //nodeValue needed for text nodes, 
                                            //innerHTML for element nodes
      }
    });
  
  $('.content').before(this.value);
}).trigger('keyup');
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 98%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
  <ol>
    <li>test data here</li>
  </ol>
</textarea>
<div class="body">
  
  <div class="content">don't change this</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

One workaround would be to get the reference to the `.content` element and `append()` it back in to the `.body` element after re-setting the `html()`. Try this:

```js
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
  var $content = $('.content');
  $(".body").html(this.value).append($content);
}).trigger("keyup")
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 98%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="body">
  <div class="content">don't change this</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to avoid appending `.content` on each keyup. (I'm working on my code editor and my <script> tag in this case is replaced with `.content`, and `<body>` tag is replaced with `.body`)

Comment: This seems the most elegant, but if there were any events registered on `.content`, they'd be lost.  See https://jsfiddle.net/L8sfx1y0/

Comment: @RickHitchcock you could append a `clone(true)` copy of the element to retain the events, although I agree this isn't the best from a performance view. Your version is better.

Answer (score 0):

you can append into `$content`rather than changing the entire html

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
 $('.body').html(this.value).append($content)
}).trigger('keyup');
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3320/

Comment: This depends on content being static (if it updates the variable will contain the old value)

Answer (score 0):

Keep HTML, CSS, and JS separate. See Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(".html").keyup(function() {
  $(".body").html(this.value)
}).trigger("keyup")
$(".css").keyup(function() {
  $(".style").html(this.value)
}).trigger("keyup")
$(".js").keyup(function() {
  $(".script").html(this.value)
}).trigger("keyup")
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 98%;
  height: 100px;
}
.tag {
  font: 700 16px/1.45 'Consolas';
  color: grey;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
<legend>HTML</legend>
<textarea class="edit html">

</textarea>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>CSS</legend>
<textarea class="edit css">
  
</textarea>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>JavaScript</legend>
<textarea class="edit js">
  
</textarea>
</fieldset>

<hr/>

<section class="printer">
  
<div class="tag">&lt;html&gt;</div>
<div class="tag">&lt;head&gt;</div>
<div class="tag">&lt;style&gt;</div>
  
<div class="print style">
  
</div>
  
<div class="tag">&lt;/style&gt;</div>
<div class="tag">&lt;/head&gt;</div>
<div class="tag">&lt;body&gt;</div>
  
<div class="print body">
 
</div>

<div class="tag">&lt;script&gt;</div>
  
<div class="print script">
  
</div>
  
<div class="tag">&lt;/script&gt;</div>
<div class="tag">&lt;/body&gt;</div>
<div class="tag">&lt;/html&gt;</div>
</section>
```